# sip stack comparison

Tags: voip, sip, pjsip, jain-sip

I want to compare opensource sip stacks like opal, pjsip, opensips etc for difference in architecture, maximum concurrent calls, memory footprint and other boundary values.

Any pointers are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well I imagine you'll end up doing a fair bit of work to set each of them up also considering that they may not all be designed for the same mode of operation; for example pjsip is usually used in SIP User Agent role whereas opensips is usually used in a Proxy or B2BUA role.

That aside one of the popular methods of testing the call throughput performance of a SIP software stack is to use the [sipp](http://sipp.sourceforge.net/) tool. The tools purpose in life is to be able to fire as many SIP INVITEs as you want at a SIP User Agent Server and provide very verbose statistics about error codes and response times.

Answer (score 1):

See also [sipsak](http://sipsak.org/) to build various scenarios.

You'll seriously have your work cut out as these don't all have the same level of operation (see sipwiz's answer) and even where they do the APIs are very different.

You should also include osip (very low-level) and eXosip (higher-level, built on osip).

Answer (score 1):

I'm extremely happy with [baresip](http://www.creytiv.com/baresip.html) ([github page](https://github.com/alfredh/baresip)). BSD-licensed. Extremely clear and portable pure C.

Its architecture is based on asynchronous IO and good set of plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, looks like PJSIP uses GPL while OPAL uses MPL, which might make OPAL much more attractive when creating commercial software.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you will be able do it directly. What I suggest is finding out which stacks are used by which open source products. And getting statistics from them.

You can find the list of vendors using the stack usually on the project page
\